# Define a method on a model that gets the count of two belongs_to records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A `question` has `upvotes` and it has `comments`. I want to define a method on the question model that gets a sum of "upvotes" and "comments", so `my_sum = @question.upvotes.count + @question.comments.count`

How am I supposed to define this method on the model in question.rb?

```
def my_sum
  return self.upvotes.count + self.comments.count
end
```

Comment: That looks about right (except that you can drop `return`), is it not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

That should have worked.  Some small changes you could make:

```
def upvotes_and_comments_count
  upvotes.size + comments.size
end
```

Use `size` so it doesn't call the sql if it doesn't need to.  You don't need 'self' here.  And return is unnecessary as papirtiger pointed out.

Comment: I get `undefined method 'upvotes_and_comments_count'` in both this case and the other

Comment: I restarted Rails after making the change... I just need to place this code within `class Question < ActiveRecord::Base ... end` correct?

Comment: Yes - the upvotes and comments instance methods will be defined on the Question class.  When this method is called, it will call those two methods and return to sum.